# Cordova and Ionic do not Install Under OS X Capitan (Version 10.11.1)

Tags: node.js, xcode, cordova, osx-elcapitan

I recently updated my Mac to OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.1) and now have trouble with my cordova and ionic installations. Both run well under Yosemite.

`$ npm –v`
shows
`$ 3.3.12`

`$ node`
shows
`$ v5.0.0`

`$ sudo npm install –g cordova ionic`
shows
`$ npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Applications/Xcode.app/–g`
`$ npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0`
`$ npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "–g" "cordova" "ionic"`
`$ npm ERR! node v5.0.0`
`$ npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12`
`$ npm ERR! path /Applications/Xcode.app/–g`
`$ npm ERR! code ENOENT`
`$ npm ERR! errno -2`
`$ npm ERR! syscall open`
`$`
`$ npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/Xcode.app/–g'`
`$ npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself`
`$ npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.`
`$ npm ERR! enoent`
`$`
`$ npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:`
`$ npm ERR!     /Applications/Xcode.app/npm-debug.log`

Here the content of this log file:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok`
`1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',`
`1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',`
`1 verbose cli   'install',`
`1 verbose cli   '–g',`
`1 verbose cli   'cordova',`
`1 verbose cli   'ionic' ]`
`2 info using npm@3.3.12`
`3 info using node@v5.0.0`
`4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting`
`5 silly install loadCurrentTree`
`6 silly install readLocalPackageData`
`7 silly fetchPackageMetaData –g`
`8 silly fetchPackageMetaData cordova`
`9 silly fetchPackageMetaData ionic`
`10 silly fetchOtherPackageData –g`
`11 silly cache add args [ '–g', null ]`
`12 verbose cache add spec –g`
`13 silly fetchNamedPackageData cordova`
`14 silly mapToRegistry name cordova`
`15 silly mapToRegistry using default registry`
`16 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`
`17 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova`
`18 silly fetchNamedPackageData ionic`
`19 silly mapToRegistry name ionic`
`20 silly mapToRegistry using default registry`
`21 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`
`22 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic`
`23 silly cache add parsed spec Result {`
`23 silly cache add   raw: '–g',`
`23 silly cache add   scope: null,`
`23 silly cache add   name: null,`
`23 silly cache add   rawSpec: '–g',`
`23 silly cache add   spec: '/Applications/Xcode.app/–g',`
`23 silly cache add   type: 'local' }`
`24 error addLocal Could not install /Applications/Xcode.app/–g`
`25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/Xcode.app/–g'`
`25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)`
`25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for –g { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/Xcode.app/–g']`
`25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: -2,`
`25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'ENOENT',`
`25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'open',`
`25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   path: '/Applications/Xcode.app/–g' }`
`26 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova`
`27 verbose request no auth needed`
`28 info attempt registry request try #1 at 16:52:51`
`29 verbose request id 37de52bb0c078959`
`30 verbose etag "3I2GKY5YJDCEH0E25NKOJONR5"`
`31 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova`
`32 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic`
`33 verbose request no auth needed`
`34 info attempt registry request try #1 at 16:52:51`
`35 verbose etag "D4ZWHYNBKT52VU9GGXKKX7DYM"`
`36 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic`
`37 http 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic`
`38 verbose headers {}`
`39 silly get cb [ 304, undefined ]`
`40 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic from cache`
`41 verbose get saving ionic to /Users/dirk/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/ionic/.cache.json`
`42 http 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova`
`43 verbose headers {}`
`44 silly get cb [ 304, undefined ]`
`45 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova from cache`
`46 verbose get saving cordova to /Users/dirk/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/cordova/.cache.json`
`47 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting`
`48 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing`
`49 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting`
`50 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing`
`51 silly install printInstalled`
`52 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/Xcode.app/–g'`
`52 verbose stack     at Error (native)`
`53 verbose cwd /Applications/Xcode.app`
`54 error Darwin 15.0.0`
`55 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "–g" "cordova" "ionic"`
`56 error node v5.0.0`
`57 error npm  v3.3.12`
`58 error path /Applications/Xcode.app/–g`
`59 error code ENOENT`
`60 error errno -2`
`61 error syscall open`
`62 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/Xcode.app/–g'`
`62 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself`
`62 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.`
`63 verbose exit [ -2, true ]`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am running both cordova and Ionic on 10.11.1 without a problem
node is 5.10
npm is 3.3.12 (because 3.4.1 crashes cordova)
ionic is 1.7.10
cordova is 5.4.0

All installed using npm via terminal after fresh 10.11.1 install. 
that being said, XCode has been downloaded and installed as well,
Suggest remove and reinstall node and npm from downloaded installer from node site. That was the path I followed.